# gcloud app deploy build fails with error module not found 'link-module-alias'

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, yarnpkg

I am trying to deploy a Node.js application to the GCP app engine but the build fails because of a module. The module in question is 'link-module-alias'. I tried removing yarn.lock to fresh install the modules.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
Step #1: INFO[0028] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...
Step #1: INFO[0038] RUN yarn install --production ||   ((if [ -f yarn-error.log ]; then       cat yarn-error.log;     fi) && false)
Step #1: INFO[0038] cmd: /bin/sh
Step #1: INFO[0038] args: [-c yarn install --production ||   ((if [ -f yarn-error.log ]; then       cat yarn-error.log;     fi) && false)]
Step #1: yarn install v1.21.0
Step #1: $ command -v link-module-alias && link-module-alias clean || true
Step #1: [1/5] Validating package.json...
Step #1: [2/5] Resolving packages...
Step #1: [3/5] Fetching packages...
Step #1: info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
Step #1: info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
Step #1: [4/5] Linking dependencies...
Step #1: [5/5] Building fresh packages...
Step #1: $ link-module-alias
Step #1: /bin/sh: 1: link-module-alias: not found
Step #1: error Command failed with exit code 127.
Step #1: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: exit status 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR:  Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/dd154faf-df52-4c34-9008-b3b963c15756?project=491794690190 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Comment: Did you try to use the --verbosity=debug flag as suggested by @ParthMehta in step 3. to get a more complete error message. Also what does the Cloud Build logs say?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your build with

1. docker --cleanup flag which cleans up the file system
2. if the above does not work try docker --no-cache which will force the docker image to rebuild all its layers
3. if 1 and 2 does not work try --verbosity=debug

and see what you get. The kaniko github page few other flags with examples which might help. See: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko

Comment: Thanks this helped. sorry for deplayed res.